# Is there a worked example of using CStrBufT with a CString?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

I stumbled on this class when browsing the internet this morning: [`CStrBufT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstrbuft-class?view=msvc-170).

I understand that it is meant to be used instead of:

```cpp
CString::GetBuffer
CString::GetBufferSetLength
CString::ReleaseBuffer
```

But the documentation lacks a usage example, and my searches on the internet don't seem to show this class being used, but the respective `CString` methods.

What is the correct way to use this wrapper when you need a buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most commonly, you use `CStrBuf` when you have to pass a string buffer to a C API that is filled by the called function. Here is an example that calls `GetModuleFileName()` from C++ (off the top of my head).

```
// assume we got a valid HMODULE somewhere
HMODULE module = ...;

// somehow decide on a buffer size; for simplicity, use a constant here
DWORD size = MAX_PATH;

CString filename;
GetModuleFileName(module, CStrBuf(filename, size), size);

// the result is now in filename

// (note: error checks omitted for brevity)
```

`CStrBuf` has an `operator LPTSTR`, i.e., it can be converted to a writable string implicitly. For this reason, it can be written as a temporary object in place of an `LPTSTR` argument (the second argument in this example).

Note that `CStrBufT` is a class template just like `CStringT` is. Stick with the specialization `CStrBuf` that is akin to `CString`.

Comment: Ok, but the docs imply to use this class wherever I need to use GetBuffer/GetBufferSetLength as I won’t have to worry about calling ReleaseBuffer.

Comment: That's correct. The class does the `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer` calls for you. That's its whole point.

Comment: I just surprised that over the years I have seen lots of answers about using GetBuffer etc but not this class I stumbled over. Anyhow, thanks for the example.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `CStrBufT` doesn't work well with APIs that report the valid string length separately (such as [`GetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw)).